# Comparing clustering of standard errors between felm and feols functions

Tags: r, regression, fixed-effects-model, high-dimensional, clustered-standard-errors

I'm using the `lfe` and `fixest` packages to run regressions with high-dimensional fixed effects. For these regressions, I would like to cluster the standard errors by several dimensions (eg. product, destination and time). However, I'm confused about the syntax and how it differs between the `felm` and `feols` commands. Would the clustering in the following two models be equivalent?

EDIT: I ran the two models and found that m2 has larger standard errors than m1.

```
m1 <- felm(y ~ x1+ x2 | fe1 + fe2|0|product + destination + time, data=df) #with lfe package
summary(m1)
m2 <- feols(y ~ x1+ x2 | fe1 + fe2, data=df) #with fixest package 
summary(m2, cluster=~product + destination + time)
```

Comment: Perhaps try it and see? If you get different results then edit that into your question.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is no single way to compute the standard-errors. The way they are computed in `fixest` and how they compare to `lfe` are explained in this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fixest/vignettes/standard_errors.html).

There were also a couple of (*minor*) bugs in the SEs in `fixest` version < 0.6.0 making the SEs look slightly different.

Here's a comparison related to your example with toy data:

```
library(fixest) ; library(lfe)
data(trade)

est_felm  =  felm(log(Euros) ~ log(dist_km) | Origin + Destination | 0 | Origin + Destination + Year, trade)
est_feols = feols(log(Euros) ~ log(dist_km) | Origin + Destination, trade)

# Same SEs but different p-values
coeftable(est_felm)
#>               Estimate Cluster s.e.   t value     Pr(>|t|)
#> log(dist_km) -2.072132    0.1516212 -13.66651 2.525297e-07
coeftable(est_feols, cluster = ~ Origin + Destination + Year)
#>               Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
#> log(dist_km) -2.072132  0.1516212 -13.66651 2.024366e-42

# Same SEs and p-values (t.df is explained in the vignette)
coeftable(est_feols, cluster = ~ Origin + Destination + Year,
          dof = dof(t.df = "min"))
#>               Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
#> log(dist_km) -2.072132  0.1516212 -13.66651 2.525297e-07
```